# Skip replace if inside specific tag

Tags: php, regex, replace

I have the following regex to detect text inside `<?php` (including the tag)

```
'/<\?php(.*)\?>/isU'
```

I also got function called compress. the function compress html content by replacing new lines, comments etc... I don't want the function to replace text inside the `<?php` tag. how can I do it using the regex above?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't just take yahoo compressor? http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/

Comment: Because I dont like to install things.. I am trying to make online tool for my self to compress..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be MUCH safer walking the DOM and operating on the text nodes. Using regex on HTML/XML is typically unsafe (there are numerous SO arguments/discussions on the issue). The essense of the problem is that regex (esp. the Javascript implementation) lacks a means to accurately establish the context and nesting of a pattern.

Comment: I tried the DOM class before, and it didnt work for me so I went to the regex.